# How to create Multi Select dropdown using Material Tailwind in react

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, tailwind-css

I am trying to build multi select dropdown using tailwind material Select and Option Component comes from @material-tailwind/react.

But whenever i try to pass array as value to Select value prop it gives below error
Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `MaterialTailwind.Select`, expected `string`

I do not want to use react-select because my over all over is designed using tailwind material

If some has the idea please tell an approach for this multi-select with tailwind material

```
<Select
  className='md:w-72'
  size='lg'
  label='Change Type'
  multiple
  value={selectedOptions}>
  {options.map((o) => {
    return <Option value={o.value}>{o.value}</Option>;
  })}
</Select>
```

Thanks!!